# one host, 2 port destination. Nginx proxy manager, docked

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

one host, 2 port destination.
Hi, i have 2 sites i need to access throw reverse proxy on same host, diferent port.

example.com/1 in 80

example.com/2 in 81

i have nginx proxy manager set up. Host example.com por 80, and i created 2 custom locations /1:80 and /2:81. /1 works fine /2 doesnt.

BUT!, if i change the site destination port to 81. /2 works, but /1 stops working.

i need that the same domain accepts 2 differents ports as destination, or custon location, directs traffic to the specific port in config.

any suggestion?

Sorry for my english

tried everything, nothing works, i suppose its easy, but i can not figure it out